# Flutter slidable : how to open action panel by tap and also close others at the same time

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_slidable library to implement a list of items. I would like to implement this open action panel by tapping the item an, at the same time, all action panels of other items should be closed.

However, I can implement both feature, but they are not at the same time. As the initial state, action panels of all the items are closed. When I tap one item, the action panel of the item is opened. Then I tap another item. The action panel of the first item is closed, but the action panel of the second item is not opened. I have to tap the second item again to open the action panel.

Can anyone please help? Thank you

Here is my code

```
SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
              closeWhenOpened: true,
              child: ListView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                controller: ctrl.scrollCtrl,
                children: ctrl.items
                    .asMap()
                    .entries
                    .map((MapEntry<int, ListItem> entry) => _buildSlidable(context, entry))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
```

and _buildSlidable is

```
Widget _buildSlidable(BuildContext context, MapEntry<int, ListItem> entry) {
    return Slidable(
      groupTag: 'gourpTag',
      startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const ScrollMotion(),
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: icon,
          );
        ],
      ),
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (layoutBuilderContext, constraints) {
          return GestureDetector(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Title'),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              final controller = Slidable.of(layoutBuilderContext)!;
              final isClosed =
                  controller.actionPaneType.value == ActionPaneType.none; // you can use this to check if its closed
              if (isClosed) {
                controller.openStartActionPane();
              } else {
                controller.close();
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```